# Uniform Convergence of Remainder exponential function

Tags: limits, derivatives, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

For $x \neq 0$, define $f(x)=\exp \left(-1 / x^{2}\right).$ Let $f(0) = 0$.

Show that the sequence of Taylor polynomials of $f$ at $x_{0}=0$ cannot possibly converge to $f$ except at the one point $x_{0}$. Thus no matter how large $k$ may be, the error $ \mid f(x)-p_{k}(x) \mid$ cannot be made arbitrarily small for any $x \neq 0$.

Interestingly, the $k$ th derivative of f at zero is equal to $0$, therefore $p_{k}=0$ for any $k$ positive integer. However, I could not understand clearly how the remainder could not be small enough to show the uniform convergence of the Lagrange remainder. Are there any alternative methods for it?

Comment: Are you sure the power is $\frac{-1}{x^{-2}} = -x^2$?

Comment: I am so sorry, modified the problem statement

Comment: Are there any further ideas for this interesting problem?

Comment: @VIVID: the OP's statement is correct. Notice that the exponential will go faster to $0$ than any reciprocal of a polynomial that  goes to $\infty$

Comment: @Snowflake: the point of the whole thing is that the Taylor expansion of any order around $0$ for the special function you have has all coefficients $0$, thus, the reminder coincides with the function itself! (that is a logical conclusion)

Comment: @VIVID I guess your kth derivative has wrong results; are you sure these are the correct values? At least, the second derivative is not right!

Comment: @Snowflake Sorry, I don't know what I was thinking about. They were just wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Show that all the derivatives of $f(x)$ are zero at $x_0=0$ and $p_k(x)=0$, hence the error cannot be smaller. For any other $x_0$, $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ simply acts as a smooth function and a proof is easy.

Comment: So basically, the difference would be simply $f(x)$, which can not be smaller than infinitesimal value epsilon? Did you mean this?

Comment: Yes. That is correct for $x_0=0$.